# Custom Master/Detail Custom List in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, custom-list

Hi we are now on removing all of our 6 Info Path Forms Applications in our SharePoint Portal and we are planning to convert it either by Custom List/SharePoint Apps/ASP.NET Application.

Now we only have 1 month or 2 just to finish the 6 application and I think that by using Custom List the development will be faster but the problem is that we have Master/Detail forms in Info Path forms which i cant find any samples doing it via SharePoint Custom List 2013.

There is a sample at this site which is done in SharePoint 2010 but cannot be done in SharePoint 2013 because it doesn't have Designer view.
 http://howididit-sharepoint.blogspot.hk/2012/12/master-detail-in-sharepoint-12.html

Do i need to pursue using Custom List or just do it by ASP.NET MVC?

Any help and suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have developed a number of approaches to using SharePoint lists for master-detail relationships.  This may be pertinent to you.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Web part connections" to achieve master/detail in custom list.
Please refer to link below for entire set of steps:
[Web part connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexma/archive/2006/04/10/610934.aspx)

"Web Part Connections" allow you to connect two different web parts on the same page. Conceptually speaking, one web part provides an input from a column to another web part's column. Depending upon the input, the target web part will get filtered.

[Web part connections in action](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1034)